# VBA Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I cannot find the problem in my code, which results in the error. I am trying to change the formula of a cell (L), if the cell (J) is not empty. I want to to run and check rows 6 to 69.

```
Sub TMark()
Do
x = 6
Set r = Sheet1.Range("Jx")
If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Lx").Formula = "=(+Jx-Fx)*Dx"
End If

x = x + 1
Loop Until x = 70
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel was treating the **"Jx"** as a string rather than **J6**.  It should be set as **("J" & x)**.

Also you are setting **x = 6** inside the Do Loop, so **x** never increments beyond **6** and the loop continues to run forever.

```
Sub TMark()

Dim x As Long
Dim r As Range

x = 6

Do
    Set r = Sheet1.Range("J" & x)
    If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & x).Formula = "=(+J" & x & "-F" & x & ")*D" & x
    End If

    x = x + 1
Loop Until x = 10

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing line 5 with `If r <> 0 Then`. I think that this would have the same effect as you are trying to get. The error was thrown up because you are not treating the range object correctly. I hope that this helps.

Comment: If I do that then I get a different error:

Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub TMark()
    Dim x As Long: x = 6
    Dim r As Range

    Do
        Set r = Sheet1.Range("J" & x)
        If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
            Sheet1.Range("L" & x).Formula = "=(J" & x & "-F" & x & ")*D" & x
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until x = 70
End Sub
```